# Multiple displays: Where did my window controls go?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, 17.04, window-manager

Here's an interesting problem, which happens fairly often, and can be temporarily fixed by restarting the DE or re-loading the Unity Theme.

Here's how the window looks on the primary display:
[image: window with controls displayed]

Now move that exact same window to a different monitor:
[image: window without close, minimize, etc controls, but a space is still there]

The window controls are now gone. They aren't just invisible, clicking there does nothing. It's strange how they still leave a space.

The theme here is a Numix derivative, but it happens with other themes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect fix, but if anyone is having this problem I wrote a script that fixes it when run without having to restart anything.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
currenttheme=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme)
currentgtk=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme)

echo $currentgtk

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
echo reset
sleep 0.2
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "$currentgtk"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "$currenttheme"
```